# Cannot properly configure teamcity to play along with mercurial when using multiple repositories not belonging in the same folder

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

I am trying to setup TeamCity build server. I am also using mercurial repositories.

My project structure is:

```
Main Folder
 -Windows Form Application Repository
 -Class library 1 Repository
    -files subrepo 1
    -files subrepo 2
    -files subrepo 3
 -Class library 2 Repository
```

I created a project in teamcity, added the 3 VCS to the project without specifying a checkout directory and the result was files from all 3 repositories in one checkout directory, resulting in build error.
I then went and changed the checkout directory of each VCS to C:\Projects. This resulted in a correct folder structure but no files in them (as if hg pull operation was done but not hg update).

Has anyone had any similar experience because I cannot find anyone complaining about such a scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set checkout rules for each of your repositories. Checkout rule of the form

```
+:.=>subdir
```

will checkout all the content of your repository to the specified subdir (see
[here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/VCS+Checkout+Rules) for details).

As I understand your 'Class library 1 Repository' has 3 subrepositories. At the moment subrepositories are not supported with server-side checkout and checkout rules are not supported with agent-side checkout (here is an [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-15984) to vote/watch for).

As a workaround, you can create separate VCS root for each subrepository, but in this case TeamCity checkout the latest version of you repository, not the tracked commit from
.hgsubstate.

Comment: I just discovered the checkout rules solutions and returned here to post the answer but you beat me to it. cudos.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do all of this using a single .hgsub in the root folder that will automatically bring in all of your other repos.  You should have a single VCS root in TeamCity that pulls from the root.

Comment: This would mean that I would have to create a new repository for each configuration and setup other repositories commit to that to trigger the VCS build trigger.

Comment: If Main Folder is in a repository with the others as subrepos this all works fine.  Main only changes when you specifically decide to take an update from a subrepo.  If you edit the subrepo and the commit and push the root using TortoiseHG it will push the subrepos too and update the hgsubstate to reflect that.

Comment: At the moment Main Folder is not a repository but rather a simple folder.Creating a main repository just for the build server to feel happy seems like a lot of overhead for me since I will have to sync the different repository revisions and commit them to the main repository so that the build server will detect the VCS change. Since it supports multiple repositories per configuration I don't know why a single repository would be required, if only the update function was propagating through all attached VCS bringing in the files and not only pulling the changes, everything would be danty.